# Python ctypes crash

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am writing unit test scripts with Python Ctypes for a SO (writen by C/C++).
But the script sometimes ( not everytime! ) crash..
the call stack is:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  PyObject_Hash (v=0x0) at Objects/object.c:1107
#1  0x080a6269 in tuplehash (v=0xb74eb02c) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
((#1..#12 are same))
#12 0x080a6269 in tuplehash (v=0xb7514e6c) at Objects/tupleobject.c:351
#13 0x0808e4f7 in PyDict_GetItem (op=0xb713ccec, key=0xb7514e6c)
    at Objects/dictobject.c:719
#14 0x080da014 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0xb705402c, throwflag=0)
    at Python/ceval.c:2124
#15 0x080de301 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0xb70a87b8, globals=0xb713ccec, 
    locals=0x0, args=0xb754d380, argcount=4, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, 
    defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3267
#16 0x0813ca0a in function_call (func=0xb7045b1c, arg=0xb754d374, kw=0x0)
    at Objects/funcobject.c:526
#17 0x080634ed in PyObject_Call (func=0xb7045b1c, arg=0xb754d374, kw=0x0)
    at Objects/abstract.c:2529
#18 0x080d6e96 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (func=0xb7045b1c, 
    arg=0xb754d374, kw=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3904
#19 0x0806348f in PyObject_CallObject (o=0xb7045b1c, a=0xb754d374)
    at Objects/abstract.c:2517
#20 0xb708670c in _CallPythonObject (pArgs=<optimized out>, flags=257, 
    converters=0xb70da75c, callable=0xb7045b1c, setfunc=0, restype=0xb7099ed4, 
    mem=0xb693c550)
    at /mnt/hgfs/host_share/Python-2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:314
#21 closure_fcn (cif=0xb70469d0, resp=0xb693c550, args=0xb693c4e0, 
    userdata=0xb70469bc)
    at /mnt/hgfs/host_share/Python-2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:375
#22 0xb709026d in ffi_closure_SYSV_inner (closure=0xb706e068, 
    respp=0xb693c55c, args=0xb693c570)
    at /mnt/hgfs/host_share/Python-2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi.c:506
#23 0xb709057a in ffi_closure_SYSV ()
    at /mnt/hgfs/host_share/Python-2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/sysv.S:199
#24 0xb6d08153 in syslog_xplatform (level=2, 
    module=0xb6f46226 "Dispatcher", line=713, 
    message=0xb693c5e5 "some message balabalabala", 
    contentoffset=70)
    at /home/core.cpp:51
****#24 is in c++ code.
```

OS : ubuntu 12.04

Py version: 2.7.10

What should I do... any advice will be appreciated.

It seemed that crashes when SO call my python callback, but I don't know why it will crash SOMETIMES..
Python code:

```
LOG_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_char_p, c_int, c_char_p);
@LOG_FUNC
def log_func_py( level, module, line, message):
    gLog.info(message);
my_lib.set_log_func( log_func_py );
```

C callback define:

```
typedef void (*log_func)(int level, const char* module, int line, const char* message);
void syslog_xplatform(esyslog_type level, const char* module, int line, const   char* message,int contentoffset)
{
    if (g_logfunc)
    {
        (g_logfunc)(level, module, line, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing code would be nice.

Comment: Tks for visit this, I have added some code.

Comment: Have you tried printf from your C code to insure you have good data there before you do the callback?

Comment: Is your app threaded?

Comment: Yes.. but it seems no limit in ctypes doc about threaded, so what should I notice? I miss sth?  Tks..

Comment: Looks like threads are OK.  Is your callback function at a global module level?  Apparently ctypes doesn't hold on to a reference for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85166/discussion-between-ravenzhang-and-patrick-maupin).

Comment: The callback is global module level. so it's very strange..

Comment: I am running into same issue. Can someone explain what's going on?